# Отключение пагинации в Django Rest fraemwork

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

У меня настроена пагинация и подключена через settings.py
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно мделать так что бы к определенному viewSet пагинация не применялась? И возвращался один объект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо добавить `pagination_class = None` в ваш **ModelViewSet**. Вот пример.

```
class MyClassBasedView(ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
```